# Low quality post failed audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I have reviewed reopen votes in which I got one low-quality post for which I failed audit.

Why such low-quality up-voted post comes in audit? I think for audit there need to check good quality not only up-vote. That doesn't make sense.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/12310607) the post where I failed the audit.

[image]

**Edit:**

Duplicate question have answer which tells *"The audit may have been incorrect"*. But, there is no any solution for that?

Comment: If last month is too old, what isn't?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara yeah. Sorry edited.

Comment: Ok, I figured it was a mistake. What exactly do you think is wrong with the question? 10 people upvoted it in a relatively short space of time. It's not super detailed, but is seems like it might be useful.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara It doesn't looks too broad.

Comment: I don't know, I'm not an expert in C++ and don't have much knowledge on this particular feature. The answerer apparently thought not, or they left a lot out.

Comment: The question in review question is asking for examples OP didn't post any code, and message tells we should reopen this question. LOL.

Comment: @Sandeep It's clear the asker really means "give me the code".  And in this case, I'm pretty okay with it, because it's a small and well-defined request whose answer is useful to people arriving from Google.  Just because you see the word "example" doesn't mean you should close it.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom As per my observation this does not fit in [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) criteria  and we should not encourage these type of questions.